# Multiple queries single formula Google Sheets

Tags: sql, google-sheets

I'm having trouble getting google sheets to run a formula and I'm not exactly sure whats wrong with it.

I know its a pretty massive query but it had no problem running it yesterday.

It looks something like this

```
=Iferror(
   Query(
     {indirect("Range "&a2&"!a:s");indirect("Range &"a3"&!a:s")},
     "select Col1, sum(Col2) group by Col1"),
   Query(
     indirect("Range "&a3&"!a:s),
     "Select A, sum(B) group by A")
 )
```

Where A2 & A3 are dates that are referenced in other tabs.

The formula goes on like this about 31 times (one for each day of the month) so it can dynamically add new data as we add it. Is there anyway I can make it run faster? I'm currently using a lot of sumifs with the same type of set up but it generally runs really slow.

Answer (score 0):

Is your trouble performance or is it something else? If the latter, share a copy of the sheet to let others help you debug.

If all you are looking for is performance improvement, one obvious observation is that the query considers only the first 2 columns, but you are passing 20 columns to it (A:S). Try querying the ranges of A:B only.

For huge performance improvements on query, MMULT() is known to help in a SUM/GROUP BY scenario. But again it's hard to say if it will help unless you show your data.